# Parse Basic Programming

Tags: basic

Receiving this error when trying to compile code on replit. I have already tried to declare two arrays, you need to use separate DIM statements for each array:

as 20 DIM W$(10)
30 DIM G$(26)

Error:  ParseError: Parse error on line 20: Unexpected token DIM

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue

```
   10 REM Hangman game
   20 REM Set up variables
   30 DIM W$(10), G$(26)
   40 LET C = 0
   50 LET I = 0
   60 LET J = 0
70 REM Set up word list
80 W$(1) = "HANGMAN"
90 W$(2) = "BASIC"
100 W$(3) = "COMPUTER"
110 W$(4) = "PROGRAM"
120 W$(5) = "VINTAGE"
130 REM Select a random word
140 LET R = INT(RND(1) * 5) + 1
150 LET W = W$(R)
160 REM Set up guess string
170 FOR I = 1 TO LEN(W)
180 G$(I) = "-"
190 NEXT I
200 REM Main game loop
210 DO
220 CLS
230 PRINT "Hangman"
240 PRINT
250 PRINT "Word: ";
260 FOR I = 1 TO LEN(W)
270 PRINT G$(I);
280 NEXT I
290 PRINT
300 PRINT "Guesses: ";
310 FOR I = 1 TO 26
320 IF G$(I) <> "-" THEN PRINT G$(I);
330 NEXT I
340 PRINT
350 INPUT "Enter a letter: ", L$
360 IF LEN(L$) > 1 THEN 400
370 IF L$ < "A" OR L$ > "Z" THEN 400
380 LET L = ASC(L$) - 64
390 GOTO 420
400 PRINT "Invalid input. Please enter a single letter."
410 GOTO 350
420 REM Check if letter is in word
430 LET F = 0
440 FOR I = 1 TO LEN(W)
450 IF MID$(W, I, 1) = L$ THEN G$(I) = L$: F = 1
460 NEXT I
470 IF F = 0 THEN C = C + 1
480 IF C = 6 THEN 600
490 REM Check for win
500 LET WN = 1
510 FOR I = 1 TO LEN(W)
520 IF G$(I) = "-" THEN WN = 0
530 NEXT I
540 IF WN THEN PRINT "You win!": GOTO 650
550 REM Check for loss
560 IF C = 6 THEN PRINT "You lose. The word was "; W: GOTO 650
570 LOOP
600 REM Draw hangman
610 PRINT " _____"
620 PRINT " | |"
630 IF C > 1 THEN PRINT " O |" ELSE PRINT " |"
640 IF C > 2 THEN PRINT "/|\ |" ELSE PRINT " |"
650 END
```

/////

I tried declaring separate arrays. I also tried running it on a vintage basic terminal, and received an error with line 150 "type mismatch"

Comment: The type mismatch is you are assigning a numeric variable (w) from a string array (w$()) change instances of w to w$ (or some other letter$).  As to the original error sounds like a bad emulator, there is no error on line 20 as that is only a remark line.

Comment: I’m not familiar with Replit but it is suspicious to me that the error occurs on the second line. Check to make sure (a) the line endings are correct for Replit, and (b) Replit doesn’t mind the indentation in front of the first six lines. That is, it may be erroring out on line 2 because it can’t parse the *file* rather than because it can’t parse the *BASIC*. (You may also wish to add the replit tag, if that tag applies to the Replit you are using.)